# Add a UIWebView inside a TTTableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

My current layout for a TTTableViewController is as the following

```
Navigation
TTTabStrip [Item1 Item2 Item3]
Table Rows
Table Rows
.
.
Table Rows
TabBar [Tab1 Tab2 Tab3]
```

What I want to do is, when clicking Item2 on the TTTabStrip, those Table Rows will be replaced by a UIWebView, but others (TTTabStrip/TabBar) remain unchanged.

Any suggestion to implement this?

Comment: I would think carefully before using multiple webviews as each one will take at least 20mb of ram.

Comment: @ade I just want to have ONE webview under the TTTabStrip, which  replace all the rows.

Comment: In that case maybe you should just overlay the webview? and hide it when it's not needed. and hide the tableview when you unhide the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can two options:

1. add a `UIWebView` on top of the `TTTableViewController` view by setting the webview's frame to the tableview's frame. This is a easy and fast solution. when someone clicks on a different tab, you will need to remove the web view from the view and release it.

   ```
   _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
   [self.view addSubView:webView];
   ```
2. you can create a new view controller with a web view, and extend a shared view controller that contains the tab bar and strip bar. So overall you will have a base controller, and 2 view controllers that extend from that base controller. I would do it only if you're planning on extending your views in the future.